# What does "encajan igual" mean in the following context?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

¿Qué significa la frase *encajan igual* en la siguiente oración?

*Cada niño toma un número de cubos que encajan igual al número de letras en su nombre.*

Me parece ser un poco torpe.

---

What does the phrase *encajan igual* mean in the following sentence?

*Cada niño toma un número de cubos que encajan igual al número de letras en su nombre.*

It seems like an awkward phrase to me.

Comment: A lo mejor se refiere a cubos que encajan entre sí...

Answer (score 4):

Efectivamente, esa frase "huele" a mala traducción. La idea es que el número de cubos que toma cada niño debe ser igual  al número de letras de su nombre. Quien tradujo la frase original (que seguramente estaba en inglés y utilizaba *match*) hizo una pobre elección en la traducción de *match* y optó por *encajar*, oscureciendo el sentido original de la frase.

Teniendo en cuenta el sentido que debe tener *match* en la frase propuesta, una posible traducción más apropiada sería:

> *Cada niño toma tantos cubos como letras tenga su nombre.*

o, en una versión más literal,

> *Cada niño toma una cantidad de cubos igual al número de letras de su nombre.*

Answer (score 0):

Loosely translated, "encajar" means "to match," and the phrase means that every child takes a number of cubes that **matches** (equally) the number of letters in their name.

Comment: I think you're on a good track, but we need to check the definition and usage -- please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Diccionario de la Lengua Española has as one of its definitions of [*encajar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EwwHYTQ):

> 13. intr. Coincidir, estar de acuerdo con un proyecto, idea o hipótesis. *Esta noticia encaja con lo que suponíamos.*

So, the sentence you cited is almost good.  It's missing the preposition *en* which is part of the expression.  Let's see if we can correct it:

> Cada niño toma un número de cubos que encaja con el número de letras en su nombre.
>    *Each child takes the number of cubes that matches the number of letters in his name.*

Note, I took "igual" out because it was superfluous.  Also, at second look, I changed the verb to singular to agree with "número."

A casual reader or listener would be able to understand the original sentence, but it would sound a bit off.